# Capturing stream via video player?

Tags: streaming, mplayer, stream

Is there a way to run stream from http://www.ustream.tv/ using mplayer or wget or anything different than a web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`vlc`**](http://www.videolan.org/index.html).

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Now to capture a network stream, open vlc then go to menu bar choose `Media` then `Open Network Stream` 
[image]

Now enter the path to stream.

[image]

Comment: with vlc you could also dump and convert the stream on the fly...

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, probably because clean link (e.g http://www.ustream.tv/creativelive)  isn't good  ?

Comment: No, that is just the page with the embedded player.

Comment: I found a kind of solution which is http://docs.livestreamer.io/ . It desn't work that well on ustream (much better on twitch) but it's watchable